# extract a methods block from a module/class

Tags: python

I would like to extract a block of statments (function) from souce code if some condition is met. e.g in the following code snippet, i would like to extract the function method2() and all its statements to another file for analyis

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
       pass
  def method1(self):
      pass
  def method2(self):
      statement1
      statement2
      ...
  def method2(self):
      print 'xyz'
```

any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

use [inspect.getsource](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource)

```
import inspect

class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
       pass
  def method1(self):
      pass
  def method2(self):
      a = 1
  def method2(self):
      print 'xyz'

print inspect.getsource(MyClass.method2)
```